# Set a pre-trained weight at keras dense layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a terrible problem on doing my work with Keras, and here's a problem;

```
encoder_path = "my own encoder path"
if (os.path.exists(encoder_path)):
    encoder = tf.keras.models.load_model(encoder_path, compile=False)
    # encoder.summary()
    print("Encoder model exist & loaded ...")

else:
    print("There is no file! Check " + encoder_path + ' ...')

## Making latent vector layer code ##
loc_z_mean = len(encoder.layers) - 11
loc_z_log_var = len(encoder.layers) - 10
z_mean = encoder.layers[loc_z_mean]
z_log_var = encoder.layers[loc_z_log_var]
print(z_mean.get_weights())
z_mean_weights = z_mean.get_weights()[0]
z_mean_bias = z_mean.get_weights()[1]
print(np.shape(z_mean_weights))
print(np.shape(z_mean_bias))
z_log_var_weights = z_log_var.get_weights()[0]
z_log_var_bias = z_log_var.get_weights()[1]

z_weights = z_mean_weights + np.exp(0.5 * z_log_var_weights)
z_bias = z_mean_bias + np.exp(0.5 * z_log_var_bias)
# z_weights_init = z_weights.numpy()
# z_bias_init = z_bias.numpy()
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, name="latent_z").set_weights([z_weights, z_bias])
# z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, kernel_initializer=z_weights_init, bias_initializer=z_bias_init, name="latent_z")
# z.trainable = False # Freeze layer
print(z)
```

I'm trying to make a new weight from former model. But it doesn't work when trying

```
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, name="latent_z").set_weights([z_weights, z_bias])
```

with this error;

```
ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "latent_z" with a weight list of length 2, but the layer was expecting 0 weights. Provided weights: [array([[0.85919297, 0.39330506, 1.4273021 , 0.780...
```

I set the shape of `z_weights` and `z_bias` size, `(16, 16)` and `(16,)` respectively since those size are exactly same as first loaded weights, but it didn't work.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke build() for the layer with the required input_shape before being able to set the weights

```
z = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, name="latent_z")
# set shape
z.build(input_shape=(100,)

# using random weights and bias for now
bias = np.random.randn(16)
weight = np.random.randn(100,16)
z.set_weights([weight, bias])
```

Without invoking build(), the layers weights are not defined since the shape of the weights depend on the shape of the input. In the above sample code, the input shape was 100 and hence the weight shape is [100,16].